# Eulerian type of integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

Could anyone give me some light on how to evaluate
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1-t}\sqrt{a+t}}{t^2}\left(1-e^{-t}-2te^{-t} \right)dt$$
where $a$ is a positive real constant.

I tried several different things including contour integral, integration by parts, and expanding the square root $\sqrt{a+t}$ with the hope that the resultant series may eventually add up to some closed form functions. None of these efforts worked. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there is a closed form? Most integrals don't have one. Maybe the best you can do is numerical methods.

Comment: Also $1-e^{-t}-2te^{-t} = -t+O(t^2)$ so it doesn't converge when $a \ne 0$

Comment: No, I do not have any good reason for a closed form. Of course if there is one that will be great. Thank you.

Comment: @reuns thank you. Oh...

Comment: Even with $a=0$, I am quite skeptical about a possible closed form (even using special functions). By the way, **Welcome to the site !**

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici For `a=0` CAS says: $\pi  \left(\frac{I_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{e}}-1\right)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you!

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thanks! The result looks neat!